# P-NP problems solved? FindBugs solves the halting prob?

Tags: algorithm, findbugs, halting-problem, p-np

There is a tool called `FindBugs` it can detect infinite never ending loops in a given program/ code base.

This implies `FindBugs` can detect if a program will end or not by analyzing the code. 
Halting problem is the problem defining that:

> Given a description of an arbitrary computer program, decide whether
>   the program finishes running or continues to run forever

So does this imply that the halting problem is solved or a subset of the halting problem is solved?

Comment: Detecting infinite loops is different from detecting whether a program will finish. I'm also sure that the program won't be able to detect arbitrary code that contains an infinite loop, especially complex ones, where there are actually real things being performed. Halting problem is regarding *every* possible program, not just *common coding mistakes*.

Comment: Jonathon Reinhart I just mentioned it because stackoverflow does not allow users to post questions with the word problem in them and as it can be seen in this case Halting Problem is the exact name given to the situation. i was just hoping for any administrators to come across it and write a better filtering algorithm with certain exclusions for exceptional cases.

Comment: @justhalf Your comment is actually what should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not solved. Findbugs only finds some of the cases of infinite never ending loops, such as this one:

```
public void myMethod() {
    int a = 0;
    while (true) {
        a++;
    }
}
```

IIRC, the only **false negative** it suffers from is, if the above method `myMethod` is never called, in which case you 'll still want to delete it as it's dead code.

It does suffers from **false positives**: there are many cases of non-ending programs that findbugs will not detect.

Comment: Likewise there are many bugs that Findbugs will not detect. But reducing your number of bugs, is *always* a good thing. So do run Findbugs.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you have a tool that **always** detects infinite loops.

Suppose there exists a *unievrsal machine* `HALT(CODE, INPUT)` that halts **iff** `CODE` halts on `INPUT`. Now consider this:

1. `if HALT(CODE, CODE)`, loop forever
2. `else halt`

If `CODE` halts on `CODE`, you'll get a contradiction, and also if it doesn't. **Why**?

Assuming `CODE` halts on `CODE`, then the program will loop forever.. meaning that... it doesn't stop..
Now assume that `CODE` **doesn't** halt on `CODE`, you'll get that.... it does stop..

Comment: Nice one :) This is similar to: "The barber cuts the hair of anyone in the town who does not cut his/her own hair. Does the barber cut his own hair?" Replace "cut hair" by `HALT(input)` and "barber" by the code above.

Comment: Indeed... Make it easier to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

If you were to make a program to analyze a program for the same platform with the same limits as the analyzing programs it's impossible for such analyzer to exist. This is known as the halting problem.

When that said, halting problem is solvable for programs that has a lot less memory consumption and code length than the analyzing program can have. Eg. I can make a halt? procedure for all 2 byte [BrainFuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck)-programs like this:

```
;; takes a valid 2 byte BF-program
;; and returns if it will halt
(define (halt? x)
  (cond ((equal? x "[]") #f)
        (else #t)))
```

A larger example is by making an interpreter and hash memory states and pc-location. If a previous state is found it's an infinite loop. Even with a very good data model the memory used by the interpreter must be considerable larger than what it interprets.

I'm thinking of constant folding programs by doing and the halting problem becomes an issue. My idea is to have a data structure that has the number of times a particular branch in AST has been seen and have a cutoff limit that is very large. Thus if the interpreter has been at a branch more than the cutoff it will end up in the compiled program instead of it's computation. It takes a lot less memory and will establish that some or all parts of a program certainly does return (halt).

Imagine this code:

```
(define (make-list n f)
   (if (zero? n)
       '()
       (cons (f) (make-list (- n 1) f))))

(define (a)
  (b))

(define (b)
  (c))

(define (c)
  (b))

(display (make-list 4 read))
(display (make-list 4 a))
```

It's actually pretty bad code since you don't know which order the input might get. The compiler get to choose whats best and it might turn into:

```
(display-const "(")
(display (read))
(display-const " ")
(display (read))
(display-const " ")
(display (read))
(display-const " ")
(display (read))
(display-const ")")
(display (cons (b) (cons (b) (cons (b) (cons (b) '())))) ; gave up on (b)
```